# iptables - Allow traffic from GRE tunnel with reject-with option

Tags: iptables, tunneling

System: CentOS 7.

`/etc/sysconfig/iptables` is like this:

```
...
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i gre1 -j ACCEPT # not working
-A OUTPUT -o gre1 -j ACCEPT # not working
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

If the last line exists, my GRE tunnel is not working, ping/everything does not work (although tcpdump captures ping packages at the other end) and if I remove the final line in the `iptables` file, everything works.

What "command" should I specify to allow all traffic from gre1 but iptables is still enforcing rules on eth0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah.. A little test confirms this solution.

```
-A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
```

using this will allow all gre packets.